# Android convertView.getTag() Error

Tags: java, android, listview

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder newsvh = null;
        ViewHolder2 imagevh = null;
        ViewHolder3 speekvh = null;
        int type = getItem(position).getChanneltype();
        if (convertView == null) {
            switch (type) {
            case 1:
                newsvh = new ViewHolder();

                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                        R.layout.news_item, null);
                newsvh.image = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.image);
                newsvh.title = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.title);
                newsvh.writer = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.writer);
                newsvh.pubdate = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pubdate);
                newsvh.click = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.click);
                convertView.setTag(newsvh);
                break;
            case 2:
                imagevh = new ViewHolder2();

                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                        R.layout.image_item, null);
                imagevh.image = (AbScaleImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.image);
                imagevh.title = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.title);
                imagevh.writer = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.writer);
                imagevh.pubdate = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pubdate);
                imagevh.click = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.click);
                convertView.setTag(imagevh);
                break;
            case 3:
                speekvh = new ViewHolder3();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                        R.layout.speekall_item, null);
                speekvh.image = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.image);
                speekvh.title = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.title);
                speekvh.writer = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.writer);
                speekvh.pubdate = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pubdate);
                speekvh.click = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.click);
                convertView.setTag(speekvh);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        } else {
            switch (type) {
            case 1:
                newsvh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                break;
            case 2:
                imagevh = (ViewHolder2) convertView.getTag();//Error
                break;
            case 3:
                speekvh = (ViewHolder3) convertView.getTag();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }
        switch (type) {
        case 1:
            newsvh.title.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
            newsvh.writer.setText(getItem(position).getWriter());
            newsvh.pubdate.setText(CommonUtil.getData(getItem(position)
                    .getPubdate()));
            newsvh.click.setText("浏览:"
                    + String.valueOf(getItem(position).getClick()));
            imageLoader
                    .DisplayImage(
                            AppConfig.IMAGE_ADDRESS
                                    + getItem(position).getLitpic(),
                            newsvh.image);
            newsvh.image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    imageWidth, (int) (imageWidth * 0.8)));
            break;
        case 2:
            imagevh.title.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
            imagevh.writer.setText(getItem(position).getWriter());
            imagevh.pubdate.setText(CommonUtil.getData(getItem(position)
                    .getPubdate()));
            imagevh.click.setText("浏览:"
                    + String.valueOf(getItem(position).getClick()));
            imagevh.image.setMargin(10);
            imageLoader
                    .DisplayImage(
                            AppConfig.IMAGE_ADDRESS
                                    + getItem(position).getLitpic(),
                            imagevh.image);
            break;
        case 3:

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, writer, pubdate, click;
        public ImageView image;

    }

    public class ViewHolder2 {
        public TextView title, writer, pubdate, click;
        public AbScaleImageView image;

    }
    public class ViewHolder3 {
        public TextView title, writer, pubdate, click;
        public ImageView image;

    }
```

Error:

```
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348): Process: com.huisifang.cms, PID: 17348
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.huisifang.cms.fragment.ChannelFragment$NewsAdapter$ViewHolder3 cannot be cast to com.huisifang.cms.fragment.ChannelFragment$NewsAdapter$ViewHolder2
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at com.huisifang.cms.fragment.ChannelFragment$NewsAdapter.getView(ChannelFragment.java:511)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2285)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5424)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3374)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3774)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3583)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7714)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2224)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-19 23:52:03.552: E/AndroidRuntime(17348):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
```

Comment: Why do you have 3 `ViewHolder` classes?

Comment: It might sound uncool, but writing a few lines that describe your problem doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should override `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType`, otherwise you will get just one null `convertView`

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getChanneltype() - 1;
}
```

and in `getView`

```
 int type = getItemViewType(position);
```

and instead of switching to `1, 2 and 3` you have to switch to `0, 1 and 2`

Comment: thank you!but there is an error!'11-20 00:14:15.582: E/AndroidRuntime(20504): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
11-20 00:14:15.582: E/AndroidRuntime(20504):  at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:7012)
11-20 00:14:15.582: E/AndroidRuntime(20504):  at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5372)
11-20 00:14:15.582: E/AndroidRuntime(20504):  at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3374)
11-20 00:14:15.582: E/AndroidRuntime(20504):'

Comment: I added ViewHolder3 to the listview first item.From the second item added ViewHolder2.Then came the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The tag assigned to `convertView` can be any one of 3 types; it is not guaranteed to match the type of the item at the current `position`. So `convertView` is being recycled from type 3, whereas the current item is type 2; this gives you your ClassCastException.

To solve it, you will have to check the type of ViewHolder you are working with in `convertView`. If it is not compatible with the current item's type, you will have to re-inflate the view and set the tag again.